# Git update from 1.8.3.4 to 1.8.4.2 on OS X

Tags: git, shell, zsh

I have `git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)`.

I downloaded [git-1.8.4.2-intel-univesal-snow-leopard.dmg](http://git-scm.com/) and installed it. I have Mavericks 10.9.1 on MacBookPro.

However it still shows 1.8.3.4.

I have `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin"` in my .zshrc.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending to the end of your PATH but you need to put the local bin dir at the beginning of the PATH. Change it to:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Then `source ~/.zshrc` and you should see the correct git.